# SessionPermSetActivation doesn't work according to specification

Tags: permissions, custom-permission

There is an issue with implemention of the following feature : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_sessionpermsetactivations.htm

In attempt to utilize the described example :

```
public PageReference activate() {
        // activate the permission set
        SessionPermSetActivation activation = new SessionPermSetActivation();
        activation.AuthSessionId = sessionId;
        activation.PermissionSetId = sessionPermSetId;
        activation.Description = 'created by SessionPermSetActivationController';
    
        insert activation;
        return null;
    }
```

Received the error:

```
FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Session permission set cannot be activated for a child session.: []
```

Is there any way to execute the above from APEX.

I have also found the way how to achieve that with Flows (https://abhinavswarup.wordpress.com/2017/10/13/session-based-permission-sets/), however would be great to know whether it could work directly from APEX.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for the parent Session, and use that if available:

```
Map<String, String> sessionInfo = Auth.SessionManagement.getCurrentSession();
String parentSession = sessionInfo.get('ParentId'), sessionId = sessionInfo.get('SessionId');

activation.AuthSessionId = parentSession!=null?parentSessionId:sessionId;
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, it worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the right answer.  No matter what I try, I get "Field is not writable - AuthSessionId".  And if you look at the reference, it doesn't allow Insert.  So the example they show isn't accurate.

Comment: The answer is correct. You are possibly running into "Field is not writable" error because your might not have `Manage Session Permission Set Activation` permission assigned.